# Dual monitor setup with portrait monitor - How to turn off artificially larger screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor, display-rotation

I think I'm turning slightly mad with this problem. I can't seem to find any other questions or solutions regarding this, yet it seems like a scenario a lot of ubuntu developers would have encountered already.

I want to turn one of my two screens into potrait mode for coding, and leave the other screen in normal landscape mode. However, when I do this using the `Displays` setting, I get into this weird mode where I have to move my mouse cursor to the edge of the screen to "move" it around. So, the screen content on both my monitors is the correct way around at least ... but this is still unbearably annoying, because I will never be able to see the entire screen at once without moving the mouse back and forth and having the entire screen content shift along with it.

I hope you have an idea of what I'm talking about here, otherwise I can try to record a video or something. My `Displays` setting pane looks like this, and I think this would be exactly what I want, if I would be able to turn that other "feature" off...

[image]